# Spring and several controllers matching a single path variable

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, controller

In a Spring application, I have a controller with the following annotation:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{category}/", method = GET)
```

I'd like to have other controllers matching a single pre-defined path variable, e.g.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/payment/", method = GET)
```

I think it is doable since I see several websites implementing this kind of URLs.

E.g. you may have several paths for the categories

```
http ://www.mysite.com/computer/
http ://www.mysite.com/smartphone/
http ://www.mysite.com/printer/
```

and then others for "static contents"

```
http ://www.mysite.com/payment/
http ://www.mysite.com/shopping-bag/
http ://www.mysite.com/wish-list/
```

Can anyone show me how to do it?

Comment: That's an interesting point. Anyway, have a look at www.zalando.de  they do this and I'd like to understand how

Comment: Try providing some examples. I can't figure out what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: @chrylis see example, or have a look at the website a mentioned in the previous comment

Comment: You... just *do* it.

Comment: Yeah, funny! I'm pretty sure that the category are resolved using a path variable, while the others are resolved using a static mapping. But maybe there is some strategy that I'm actually missing

Answer (score 2):

I googled a little bit and I found within the [Spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) something that I never tried. I think you could use regex into the request mapping to do the trick.

The dynamic path variables should stay as you described, i.e.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{category}/", method = GET)
public String dynamicController(@PathVariable String category){
  ...
}
```

This in theory will match all the URLs like:

```
protocol://localhost:8080/123/
protocol://localhost:8080/random-text/
protocol://localhost:8080/whatever-it-comes/
```

The static controller should be changed like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{accepted_path:^payment$}/", method = GET)
public String staticController(){//you don't need to consume the path
  //variable accepted_path
  ...
}
```

The use of the regex `^payment$` should ensure that the URL

```
protocol://localhost:8080/payment/
```

will be binded by `staticController` only.

You could also append several accepted path variables. E.g. if the `staticController` must match the following URLs

```
protocol://localhost:8080/payment/
protocol://localhost:8080/pay/
```

Then you should replace `"/{accepted_path:^payment$}/"` with `"/{accepted_path:^payment|pay$}/"`.

Is not tested, but should do the trick!

Comment: Thanks Ro, I'll do a try in the evening

Answer (score -2):

It is doable like the way you did already. If my site is http://example.com-

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

above code will create http://example.com/test

If I want an URI with static name and a variable (http://example.com/test/variableName) then I would use-

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test/{variableName}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Comment: That's not what I asked

Comment: From the description, appears like you want to create a URI www.mysite.com/wish-list, where wish-list is hardcoded. Is not it?