# Regex for matching string not ending or containing file extensions

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation

In a Java application, I need to write a `String` containing a regex for URIs, so that the URI does not contains character sequences like `.js?`, `.css?` and `.jpg?`, but are also not ending with `.js`, `.css` and `.jpg`

I made the following:

```
(?:.js|.css|.jpg)$|(?:.js[?]|.html[?]|.jpg[?])
```

Which basically matches all the URIs ending with the given file extensions or containing the file extension plus the question mark.

How can I do the negation of the and of the previous conditions?

So, for instance I expect that the following URI will match

```
"/a/fancy/uri/.js/which/is/valid"
```

but both the following will not

```
"/a/fancy/uri/which/is/invalid.js"
"/a/fancy/uri/which/is/invalid.js?ver=1"
```

Comment: Are you trying to match invalid URLs or valid URLs?

Comment: You should use the URI class to extract the path before: http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/URI.html

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I cannot. See my comment to the accepted answer. I use it in a Spring annotation, to filter a placeholder.

Comment: For the downvoter, next time spend two seconds to explain why!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use two alternations in a negative look ahead:

```
^(?!.*\.(js|css|jpg)($|\?)).*
```

This regex matches *valid* input. In java:

```
if (url.matches("^(?!.*\\.(js|css|jpg)($|\\?)).*")
    // url is OK
```

If you want to match *invalid* input, use a positive look ahead:

```
if (url.matches("^(?=.*\\.(js|css|jpg)($|\\?)).*")
    // url is not OK
```

Comment: Perfect! I'm using it in combination with this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37578136/1983997) on how to use placeholders in Spring controllers

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying match invalid URLs, this should do it:

```
String regex = ".*\\.(js|css|jpg)($|\\?.*)";
System.out.println("/a/fancy/uri/which/is/invalid.js?ver=1".matches(regex));
System.out.println("/a/fancy/uri/which/is/invalid.js".matches(regex));
System.out.println("/a/fancy/uri/.js/which/is/valid".matches(regex));
```

Output:

```
true
true
false
```

Comment: I'd like to match if the url is valid, so for instance has not to end with .css or has not to contains .css?